# Get ID from a Row in a Interactive Report

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an Interactive Report. The Interactive Report is in a form. There are images and other columns, like the ID, in the Report. How can I get the ID of the selected Row and store it in a Page Item?

Comment: There is no concept of a "selected row" in an interactive grid. Are you using a checkbox ? Or does the user click on an image or cell in the row ?

Answer (score 3):

This is an example based on the "emp" table in the emp/dept dataset. Functionality: when user clicks on an employee name, the empno of that user is set in page item P44_ITEM.

IR source:

```
select EMPNO,
       ENAME,
       JOB,
       MGR,
       HIREDATE,
       SAL,
       COMM,
       DEPTNO
  from EMP
```

There is a page item P44_ITEM that should be set to the EMPNO when the column ename is clicked in the report.

In the report, set the attribute "Column Formatting > HTML Expression" for the column "ENAME" to value `<div class="sel-ename" data-empno="#EMPNO#">#ENAME#</div>`. Explanation: wrap a div around the text, and add a class "sel-ename" to the cell and a "data-" attribute containing the empno value for the current row.

Create a dynamic action:

- Event: Click
- Selection Type: jQuery Selector
- jQuery Selector: .sel-ename

Create a true action for the dynamic action

- Action: Set Value
- Set Type: javascript Expression

```
this.triggeringElement.dataset['empno']
```

- Affected element P44_ITEM

Save and run.